# Split a file into multiple files by writing lines between 2 patterns to a new file

Tags: perl

This is the input File:

```
#cat myfile
-- START
whatever
whatever
-- END

-- START
whatever
whatever
-- END

-- START
whatever
whatever
-- END

-- START
whatever
whatever
-- END
```

I need to grab lines between `-- START` and `-- END` and write those lines to a separate file. So in this use-case, I should have 4 files created as below:

```
# cat file1
whatever
whatever

# cat file2
whatever
whatever

# cat file3
whatever
whatever

# cat file4
whatever
whatever
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<", "/var/tmp/myfile");
my $counter = 0;

while (<$fh>)
{
    if (/START/../END/)
    {
        my $filename = "/var/tmp/file".$counter;
        open (my $oh, ">", $filename);
        print $oh $_;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

**ISSUE:** My code is creating one file  for **each** line that is found inside the `-- START` and `-- END`

Could you help me figure out how to fix this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening new file for every line, it should be opened on beginning of each range.

Use the return value of the range to determine when the file should be opened and to print only those lines between the boundary conditions.

```
my $oh;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my $range = /START/ .. /END/ ) {
        # Start of Range - Open the file handle
        if ( $range == 1 ) {
            my $filename = "/var/tmp/file" . $counter++;
            open( $oh, ">", $filename ) or die $!;

        # Print until End of Range
        } elsif ( $range !~ /E/ ) {
            print $oh $_;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input separator to your "-- END" token so the file is read in in chunks delimited by "-- END". A regex can then be used to capture the info you want. I've commented out your file I/O lines and used local data so you can run the code to check it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10";
use Data::Dumper;

#open (my $fh, "<", "/var/tmp/myfile");
my $counter = 0;

$/ = "-- END";
# while (<$fh>)
while (<DATA>)
{   if (/START\s*(\S.+?)\s*-- END/ms)
    {
    #    my $filename = "/var/tmp/file".$counter;
    #    open (my $oh, ">", $filename);
    #    print $oh $1;
        say "file $counter\n$1";
        $counter++;
    }
}

__DATA__

-- START
whatever1
whatever2
-- END

-- START
whatever3
whatever4
-- END

-- START
whatever5
whatever6
-- END

-- START
whatever7
whatever8
-- END
```

Output (goes to STDERR, but obviously you'd uncomment the lines that read and write to files):

```
file 0
whatever1
whatever2
file 1
whatever3
whatever4
file 2
whatever5
whatever6
file 3
whatever7
whatever8
```

Comment: could you explain this `/START\s*(\S.+?)\s*-- END/ms` regex please.

Comment: `START` => search for "START"; `\s*` => 0 or more whitespace characters;  `\S` => non-whitespace character;  `.+?` => match everything up to the next bit of the regex;  `\s*` => 0 or more whitespace characters; `-- END` => text string. The brackets capture the content that starts with the first non-whitespace character after "START" up to the whitespace that precedes "-- END". The operators `ms` mean treat the whole thing as a single line and allow `.` to match line breaks. See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a good intro to perl regex.

Comment: Thanks for the regex explanation. +1.